# Trading view widget - any way to change the 'invalid symbol' text?

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm using trading view's chart widget (https://in.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/).
The issue is that whenever I'm trying to change the symbol programatically from JS, if the symbol doesn't exist with TradingView, it throws an 'Invalid Symbol' error.

Is there a way to display a custom message instead of the default one?

Since my data provider is different hence sometimes the symbols don't match.

Any help would be appreciated.